# How to keep some of the results of the NestList

Tags: programming, functions, functional-style

I'm using some iterative arithmetics to calculate wave propagation with the help of NestList. I have to use a small step size for iteration to guarantee the accuracy, which lead to too much data (e.g, 10^6 points) for further plotting, and the results consumes too much memories. Is there any clever way to cope with it? I didn't intend to use loops.

This is a simplified example:

```
NestList[Sin, 1, 10^6]
```

One of my idea is to use `Sow` and `Reap`. But I've no idea to integrate them with `NestList` or `Nest`

Any idea???

Comment: You've tried `NestList[Nest[f, #, k] &, start, m]`?

Comment: Very good idea.

Comment: @J.M. Surely deserves to be an answer ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Due to insistent public demand:

If, in a sequence of iterates $\{x,f(x),f(f(x)),\dots\}$, one only needs every $k$-th iterate (say, for $k=3$, you want $\{x,f(f(f(x))),f(f(f(f(f(f(x)))))),\dots\}$), then one can cleverly combine `Nest[]` and `NestList[]` like so:

```
NestList[Nest[f, #, k] &, start, n]
```

which yields a list containing the zeroth, $k$-th, $2k$-th, ... $nk$-th iterates.

Answer (score 12):

```
Fold[f[#1] &, x, Range[#]] & /@ Range[0, 9, 3]
(* or *)
Nest[f, x, #] & /@ Range[0, 9, 3]
(* both give: *)
{x, f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]]]}
```

EDIT: a variation on the second method:

```
nestSkip[f_, x_, stepsize_Integer, numsteps_Integer] := 
   Nest[f, x, stepsize #] & /@ Range[0, numsteps]
(* examples: *)
nestSkip[g, y, 2, 2]
(* ==>  {y, g[g[y]], g[g[g[g[y]]]]} *)
nestSkip[# + 5 &, 2, 3, 3]
(* ==> {2, 17, 32, 47}  *)
```

Comment: Another very clever solution.

Comment: Thank you @yulinlinyu.

Answer (score 5):

J. M.'s method is elegant but in some cases it is not optimal.  This is because the inner `Nest[f, #, k] &` does not compile the same as an explicit series of function calls.  In advantageous cases if we expand the inner operation in advance we can have very large performance gains.

```
jmNest[f_, k_, n_, start_] :=
  NestList[Nest[f, #, k] &, start, n]

wNest[f_, k_, n_, start_] :=
  NestList[Evaluate @ Nest[f, #, k] &, start, n]
```

A favorable test case:

```
jmNest[1 + # &, 200, 1*^5, 10`] // RepeatedTiming // First
wNest[1 + # &, 200, 1*^5, 10`]  // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.2407
>
> 0.00191
> ```

Here we get more than two orders of magnitude improvement, and it's easy to understand why as 200 applications of `1 + # &` reduces to `200 + # &`.

In a less trivial case such as three applications of `Sin`, which does not reduce to a simpler formula, we still have an improvement:

```
jmNest[Sin, 3, 1*^6, 10`] // RepeatedTiming // First
wNest[Sin, 3, 1*^6, 10`]  // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.08481
>
> 0.05829
> ```

There are of course pathological cases as well where the symbolic expansion is far uglier than the sequential application:

```
jmNest[3 + # + Sqrt[# + 7] &, 15, 30, 10`] // RepeatedTiming // First
wNest[3 + # + Sqrt[# + 7] &, 15, 30, 10`]  // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.000460
>
> 0.703
> ```

I cannot think of a simple way to intelligently select between original and pre-expansion methods that does not introduce significant overhead.  There is enough potential difference in speed that perhaps a [`ParallelTry`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTry.html) is worth that overhead if unused cores are available for use.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not as elegant as JMs excellent solution, but it does use `Sow` and `Reap` as the OP requested and avoids repeated recalculation of intermediate results.

```
Clear[selectiveNestList];
selectiveNestList[function_, step_, iterations_, initialValue_] := 
 Reap[Nest[
     With[{s = function[First@#]}, 
       If[Mod[Last@#, step] === 0, 
        Sow[s]; {s, Last@# + 1}, {s, Last@# + 1}]] &, {initialValue, 
      0}, iterations   ]][[2, All, All, 1]] // First
```

And in use:

```
selectiveNestList[Cos, 2, 9, 4]
```

> {4, Cos[Cos[4]], Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[4]]]],Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[4]]]]]], 
>    Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[Cos[4]]]]]]]]}