# About minimizing calculations when using ComposeList

Tags: functions, functional-style

I have a lot of functions to use in a iterative way, and I need some of the calculation results. For example:

```
 func = Function[{s}, s Sin[#] &] /@ Range[100];
 ComposeList[func, x][[1 ;; ;; 10]]
```

Apparently, this code calculates much more than necessary. Especially, a lot of time is needed for the calculation when the length of `func` list is very long and when the `Function` is very complicated (e.g. `Length@func = 1024` and the function is `Fourier`);

**Is there any elegant way to reduce the calculation?**

***Edit***

Perhaps I should say more about the fact that this code calculates than necessary.

For example,

```
  func = Function[{s}, s Sin[#] &] /@ Range[10];
   result=ComposeList[func, x][[1 ;; ;; 5]]
```

(*

{x, 5 Sin[4 Sin[3 Sin[2 Sin[Sin[x]]]]], 
 10 Sin[9 Sin[
     8 Sin[7 Sin[6 Sin[5 Sin[4 Sin[3 Sin[2 Sin[Sin[x]]]]]]]]]]}

*)

Now we can see that result[[2]]   (i.e., 5Sin[4 Sin[3 Sin[2 Sin[Sin[x]]]]]) is also appeared inside  result[[3]]    (i.e., 10Sin[...5Sin[4 Sin[3 Sin[2 Sin[Sin[x]]]]]], so the evaluation for 5Sin[4 Sin[3 Sin[2 Sin[Sin[x]]]]] is repeated twice here.

The repetition will be very large with an increase of Length[func], which will be much more time-consuming than it is required. This is my point here (Up to now, Rojo has gotten the point and solved it ).

Comment: Doesn't `Table[(Composition @@ Reverse[Take[func, k]])[x], {k, 0, 100, 10}]` do what you want?

Comment: "Apparently, this code calculates much more than necessary." -- what leads you to believe that?  `ComposeList` is normally quite efficient.  Is there some symbolic pre-simplification that you what to leverage in your application?

Comment: @J.M && Mr.Wizard, the code proposed by J.M works well, but with the same problem as mine. (i.e., 10 Sin[9 Sin[8 Sin[7 Sin[6 Sin[5 Sin[4 Sin[3 Sin[2 Sin[Sin[x]]]]]]]]]] will be caculated many times if Length@@func is very large, that is the problem I want to get rid of.)

Comment: What is your evidence that it is calculated many times?  Each function is only applied *once*, to the result of the previous function application.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, See my edit.

Comment: But yulinlinyu, it's *not*, it's *not* calculated twice; you're looking at an unevaluated expression of nested functions; how else is *Mathematica* supposed to represent this for you?  Try this: `list = Table[(Print@#; #) &, {5}];
ComposeList[list, "print me"];`  - you will see that it is only printed five times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the problem but I have the hunch that the best answer is: no it won't calculate that many times. If the source of inefficiency you see is the fact of getting 9 out of 10 intermediate results are being dropped in the end, I see the point.

If this is the point, then you could do

```
ComposeList[
 Composition @@@ Reverse /@ Partition[func, 10, 10, 1, {}], x]
```

Otherwise, you're mistaken... Try, for example,

```
func = Function[{s}, s (Print[#]; Sin[#]) &] /@ Range[10];
ComposeList[func, x]
```

and see how you get each function evaluated only once, and you don't get the innermost `Sin` evaluated 10 times (if that was the case, the `Print` would be evaluated with it since both are part of the same function`)

Comment: ,thank you very much, the code ComposeList[
 Composition @@@ Reverse /@ Partition[func, 10, 10, 1, {}], x] is just what I want. I'm sorry for the words limits in the comment. See more explanations in the next comment.

Comment: (Continued)I have use NestList[Nest[f, #, k] &, start, n] proposed by J.M. (seen here [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-to-keep-some-of-the-results-of-the-nestlist)) when the iterative function is the same (it is Sin in my example in NestList[Nest[f, #, k] &). Now here the function is not the same (it is Function[{s}, s Sin[Sow[#]] &]). Your solution in this post resembles very much with NestList[Nest[f, #, k] & proposed by J.M., and I think it is very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `Reap` and `Sow` could be used here:

```
func = Function[{s}, s Sin[Sow[#]] &] /@ Reverse@Range[100];

lst = Reap[(Composition @@ func)[x]];

lst[[2, 1]][[1 ;; ;; 10]]
```

The `Composition` is walked through only once, and we collect the intermediate results in passing. Not sure if this more elegant - with the example you give, the result in `Reap` looks the same as what your `ComposeList` would have produced.

Answer (score 0):

I my results this is therefore important because it shows a solution to the problem how to formulate the famous Ramanujan representation of the number 3.

```
n = 19; func = Function[{s}, Sqrt[1 + s*#] &] /@ (n + 1 - Range[n]);
ComposeList[func, x][[1 ;; ;; n]]
N[(ComposeList[func, x][[1 ;; ;; n]] /. x -> 1), n]
```

func is a way to write in Mathematica a list with a parameter both in rising and in decreasing order that is suitable for `Composition` or `ComposeList` to be evaluated!.

It other usage, the pure function symbol cases trouble for the evaluation step.

The sequence convergence strictly monotone rising to 2. Ramanujan problem was  just omit the first step and have 3 for the rest of the sequence. Look at [Ramanujan the greatest mathematical prodigy](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/ramanujan-the-greatest-mathematical-prodigy-90b3ee465457). So the solved miracle is in the last row of my input. The magic stems from the leading parameter $n$ of my input.

Mathematica has layout problems for this size of the parameter already.

The part built-in is the big step ahead seemingly. This one uses the Span built-in.

[image: visual and prior solutions]