# Computing only Prime Powers with NestList

Tags: recursion

Is there a simple way to compute only prime powers of a function f with NestList? That is, I want to compute:

```
{f[x_0], f^2[x_0]=f[f[x_0]], f^3[x_0], f^5[x_0]...}
```

up to some specified prime power. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have f(x) and you want results up to 10

```
n=10;    
NestList[f,x,n][[#+1]]&/@Prime[Range@PrimePi@n]
```

> {f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]}

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using Compose:

```
n = 10; ComposeList[ConstantArray[f, n], f[x]][[#]] & /@ Prime[Range@PrimePi@n]

{f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to accumulate the nestings, i.e. use the previous nesting as the starting point for the next one:

```
primeNest[f_, x_, n_] := FoldList[Nest[f, ##] &, f[f[x]], Differences[Prime[Range[n]]]]

primeNest[f, x, 5]
```

> ```
> {f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], 
>   f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]]]]]}
> ```

```
(Depth /@ primeNest[f, x, 20]) - 1
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

One can in fact use `NestWhile[]` along with `NestList[]`, in the same spirit as [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7150):

```
NestList[NestWhile[f, f[#], ! PrimeQ[Depth[#] - 1] &] &, x, 5]
   {x, f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]], 
    f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]]]]]}
```

Here is another variation which yields the same result:

```
NestList[Nest[f, #, NextPrime[Depth[#] - 1] - Depth[#] + 1] &, x, 5]
```

---

The last few solutions have the flaw of relying on `Depth[]`, which is not very useful if the function to be iterated is even moderately complicated. Nevertheless, these can be modified like so:

```
NestPrimeList[f_, x_, n_Integer?NonNegative] := Module[{p = 0, r = x, $1},
    Prepend[Reap[Do[Sow[r = Nest[f, r, -p + (p = NextPrime[p])], $1], {n}], $1][[2, 1]], x]]
```

Example:

```
Exponent[#, x] & /@ NestPrimeList[x # + 1 &, 1, 5]
   {0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an elegant and smart way to do it but here is one way.

```
  exp = NestList[g, x, 12];
  selector = PrimeQ[LeafCount /@ exp - 1];
  Pick[exp, selector] /. {g -> f, x -> x0}
```

> {f[f[x0]], f[f[f[x0]]], f[f[f[f[f[x0]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x0]]]]]]], 
>    f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x0]]]]]]]]]]]}

Answer (score 1):

After a `For[]` loop faux pas, and after receiving the splendid advice **below** came up with this ...

```
n = 5;
ls = {};
Table[(Q = f[x]; 
   Do [Q = Map[f, Q], {j, Range[Prime[k] - 1]}]; 
       ls = Join[ls, {Q}];), {k, Range[n]}];
Print[ls]
```

Here is the result:

```
{f[f[x]],f[f[f[x]]],f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]],f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]],f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]]]]]}
```

Perhaps it is time to `Table[]` this discussion:

```
 n = 5;
 ls = {};
 Table[(Q = f[x]; 
    Table[Q = Map[f, Q], {j, Range[Prime[k] - 1]}]; 
    ls = Join[ls, {Q}]), {k, Range[n]}];
 Print[ls];
```

Comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, here it is with `For[]` replaced by `Do[]`:                                 `n = 5;
ls = {};
Do [
 (
  Q = f[x]; Do [Q = Map[f, Q], {j, Range[Prime[k] - 1]}];
  ls = Join[ls, {Q}]
  ), {k, Range[n]}]
Print[ls]`

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[primesNest0]
primesNest0[f_, x_, n_] := Nest[f, x, #] & /@ Prime[Range@PrimePi@n]
primesNest0[f, x, 10]
```

> {f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]}

Also

```
ClearAll[primesNest1]
primesNest1[f_, x_, n_] := Fold[#2@# &, x, ConstantArray[f, #]] & /@ Prime[Range@PrimePi@n]

primesNest1[f, x, 10]
```

> {f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]}

and

```
ClearAll[primesNest2]
primesNest2[f_, x_, n_] := Compose[##&@@ConstantArray[f, #], x] & /@ Prime[Range@PrimePi@n]
primesNest2[f, x, 10]
```

> {f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]}

and

```
ClearAll[primesNest3]
primesNest3[f_, x_, n_] := Composition[## & @@ ConstantArray[f, #]][x] & /@ 
  Prime[Range@PrimePi@n]
primesNest3[f, x, 10]
```

.    {f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]], f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]], f[f[f[f[f[f[f[x]]]]]]]}